# Settings a static delegate property from PowerShell (or passing a delegate to the constructor)

Tags: powershell, delegates

We have a .Net object that has a static delegate (a data access strategy) that has to be set before the object can be instantiated.  The delegate can also be passed in through one of the constructor overloads.

I have another object that has the delegate that I need to set, but I can't figure out in PowerShell how to do so.  Does anyone know how to set a static delegate property or pass a delegate into a constructor in PowerShell?

I want to do something similar to this:

```
[DALObject]$db = New-Object DALObject;
[UnitOfWork]::Strategy = $db::CreateContext;
```

or

```
[DALObject]$db = New-Object DALObject;
[UnitOfWork]$uow = New-Object UnitOfWork($db::CreateConext);
```

Just for reference I am trying to reproduce the comparable C# code:

```
DalObject db = new DALObject();
UnitOfWork.Strategy = db.CreateContext;
```

or

```
UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(db.CreateContext);
```

**Edit**:  To clarify Strategy is a static delegate

```
Public static Func<DataContext> Strategy
```

and CreateContext is an instance method that I want to set to that delegate, either by setting the static Property or by passing in the method to the constructor.

Another option would be if there is there a way in PowerShell to create an anonymous delegate like this in C#:

```
 UnitOfWork.Strategy = delegate()
            {
                var ctx = db.CreateContext();
                return ctx;
            };
```

Comment: If you try to access `CreateContext` like `$db.CreateContext` it will maybe work. (from your C# example it looks like `CreateContext` is not static property, but instance property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access static members via an instance object (assuming here that CreateContext is a static property although it is named like a method).  Try this:

```
[DALObject]$db = New-Object DALObject; 
[UnitOfWork]::Strategy = [DALObject]::CreateContext
```

or if it is a method

```
[DALObject]$db = New-Object DALObject; 
[UnitOfWork]::Strategy = [DALObject]::CreateContext()
```

OTOH if CreateContext is an instance member then change the `[DALObject]::CreateContext` to `$db.CreateContext` with or without parens depending on whether it is a method or not.

**Update**: In the case of assigning a scriptblock to a generic delegate, there is no built-in way to make this work AFAIK. Check out this [blog post for a potential work-around](http://arildf.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E99F8B43533149B0!144.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=28800297).